# how to share Docker Oracle database file to a volume host

Tags: oracle, docker

I can't share a oracle directory from wnameless/oracle-xe-11g docker container using -v `pwd`/u01:/u01. 
I've got an empty directory so how to manage user id within a docker command line?

Comment: Can you explain in more details what you've tried and what failed?
And what's `pwd/u01:u01`? did you mean `$(pwd)/u01:u01`?

Comment: Yes, it's $(pwd)/u01:01 , I am wondering that is a user permission issue on the hosts.

Comment: ok, I used a docker volume named  oracle_data and I mapped it to the oracle directory /u01, now all my oracle data are persistent on my local host.